# Are there any multi-cellular organisms out there that do not sleep?

Tags: sleep

Looking around I see animals - ants, bees, birds, lizards, roaches all the way up to humans appear during a part of the day and not other parts. I would guess there is a sleep/recovery cycle involved.

Is there any multi-cellular organism with a nervous system, on record, that works without sleep/rest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you may want to re-state your question. There are numerous multi-cellular organisms without a nervous system. So you could say that they never sleep: sponges, plants, mushrooms.

This [paper on the evolution of sleep](http://cache.orn.mpg.de/nwg/rattenb/Lesku2006a.pdf) concludes:

> A phylogenetic evaluation of sleep demonstrates that all
>   mammals, birds, and reptiles engage in sleep, and evidence
>   for sleep in amphibians, ﬁshes, and invertebrates is strong if
>   not certain.

So it seems that once you have a nervous system, you also have some rest periods. However, it may not be clear if the rest periods are dictated by the lifestyle (e.g. nocturnal foraging) or by a requirement to "recharge" the nervous system.

Comment: That paper does not exist there. Do you have another link or just title/author

Comment: Google is your friend :) John A. Lesku, Niels C. Rattenborg, and Charles J. Amlaner. "The Evolution of Sleep: A Phylogenetic Approach" Sleep: A Comprehensive Handbook. Ed. Teofilo L. Lee-Chiong. Hoboken, NJ: J. Wiley and Sons, 2006. 49-61.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find an accessible copy though.